# In lua how to use load file variable in main file

Tags: lua, load, lua-table

my main file syntax is bellow

```
dofile("subFile.lua")
main('a')
print(subVariable)
```

my sub file syntax is bellow

```
local subVariable=""
function main(x)
 subVariable="from sub"
end
```

my subfile contain variable named **subVariable** want to use this variable in my main file ,why i always get nil.

How to use main file variable in **subfile** and **subfile** variable in main file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a local. Remove the " local" and it'll work.

Locals are only accessible by the functions and code behind it.